# grep every other occurrence of a value

Tags: grep

I have an output file with multiple occurrences of a value. E.g.:

```
value 123  
value 111  
value 456  
value 111  
value 789  
value 111
```

If I use the following command, I can print all the occurrences of 'value':

```
grep 'value ' file_name
```

But I only want to print every other occurrence. Is there some way that I can edit my command to do this?

Comment: What's expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner to filter the results of `grep`:

```
grep 'value' file_name | perl -ne 'print if $. % 2;'
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

`$.` : Current input line number.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or with `awk`:

```
grep value YourFile | awk 'NR%2'
value 123  
value 456  
value 789
```